# Updating a string from a ΤextΒox

Tags: c#, string

In the program I'm making, I made a string in Settings, called "Tickers". The scope is Application, and the value is "AAPL,PEP,GILD" without the quotes.

I have a RichTextBox, called InputTickers where a user should put in stock tickers, such as AAPL, SPLS, and more. You get the point. When they click the button below the InputTickers, I need it to get Settings.Default["Tickers"]. Next, I need it to check is any of the tickers they typed in, are already in the Tickers list. If not, I need them added in.

After adding them in, I need to turn it back into the Tickers string to store in the Settings again.

I'm still learning coding, so this is my best guess, for how far I have gotten on this. I can't quite think of how to get this done correctly, though.

```
private void ScanSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declare and initialize variables
    List<string> tickerList = new List<string>();


    try
    {
        // Get the string from the Settings
        string tickersProperty = Settings.Default["Tickers"].ToString();

        // Split the string and load it into a list of strings
        tickerList.AddRange(tickersProperty.Split(','));

        // Loop through the list and do something to each ticker
        foreach (string ticker in tickerList)
        {
            if (ticker !== InputTickers.Text)
                 {
                     tickerList.Add(InputTickers.Text);
                 }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot save back Application-scoped settings at runtime, I'm afraid. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try Likes this ,

```
 foreach (string ticker in tickerList)
    {
        if (InputTickers.Text.Split(',').Contains(ticker))
             {
                 tickerList.Add(InputTickers.Text);
             }
    }
```

If your input string has space ,

```
        if (InputTickers.Text.Replace(" ","").Split(',').Contains(ticker))
         {

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ extension methods for collections. Results in much easier code. First, split the string from the settings and add the items to the collection. Second, split (you forgot that) the string from the text box and add those items, too. Third, use extension method to get the distinct list.

```
// Declare and initialize variables
List<string> tickerList = new List<string>();

    // Get the string from the Settings
    string tickersProperty = Settings.Default["Tickers"].ToString();

    // Split the string and load it into a list of strings
    tickerList.AddRange(tickersProperty.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    tickerList.AddRange(InputTickers.Text.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    Settings.Default["Tickers"] = String.Join(',', tickerList.Distinct().ToArray());
    Settings.Default["Tickers"].Save();
```

Comment: Hmmm, that does look good to me, so I tried it out. Some parts of it aren't working, so I've been googling it. Can't seem to figure out how to fix it. 

SplitOptions doesn't exist in the current context. Lets try and fix that one first. Am I missing a special namespace for it? If so, I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: Use the Intellisense of VisualStudio and you will find the correct version. I first wrote my answer without VisualStudio. Now I checked it and corrected the code/methods above. Check it out.